# How to combine arduino programm with astar algorithm?

Tags: python, arduino

I need to combine arduino with astar algorithm to controll robot. We have 6x6 area where robot need to ride and the controll (F (front),L(left),R(right)) must be write in python code. So I have arduino serial code and I find astar algorithm and programm to controll motors with arduino. How I can combine serial code and astar algorithm to controll the robot in python?

Serial code to connetc with arduino in python

```
import serial # pip install pyserial

"""
Inside serial library (module), Serial class is used to define port and baudrate
"""
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600) # Same baudrate, as in Arduino program
print('Established serial connection to Arduino')



while True:
    """ Reading from Serial port """
    inp = input("Write one character: ")
    arduino.write(bytes(inp, 'utf-8')) # writing 
    False
```

Astar algorithm what I found

```
class Node():
    """A node class for A* Pathfinding"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = position

        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position


def astar(maze, start, end):
    """Returns a list of tuples as a path from the given start to the given end in the given maze"""

    # Create start and end node
    start_node = Node(None, start)
    start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
    end_node = Node(None, end)
    end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

    # Initialize both open and closed list
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    # Add the start node
    open_list.append(start_node)

    # Loop until you find the end
    while len(open_list) > 0:

        # Get the current node
        current_node = open_list[0]
        current_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = item
                current_index = index

        # Pop current off open list, add to closed list
        open_list.pop(current_index)
        closed_list.append(current_node)

        # Found the goal
        if current_node == end_node:
            path = []
            current = current_node
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.position)
                current = current.parent
            return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

        # Generate children
        children = []
        for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares

            # Get node position
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])

            # Make sure within range
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue

            # Make sure walkable terrain
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
                continue

            # Create new node
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

            # Append
            children.append(new_node)

        # Loop through children
        for child in children:

            # Child is on the closed list
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue

            # Create the f, g, and h values
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h

            # Child is already in the open list
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue

            # Add the child to the open list
            open_list.append(child)


def main():

    maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    start = (0, 0)
    end = (7, 6)

    path = astar(maze, start, end)
    print(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 1. Combine both script into one file
2. Out of `path` list you need to get command list e.g [(0, 0), (1, 1)] -> ["F", "R"]. But it seems that A* allows diagonal moves which robot can't do so you need to ban diagonal moves or something.
3. Iterate through command list and send it one by one to the robot

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the direction of movement from start to finish as [turtle like commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) (with the constraints of your system: turns are 90 degrees only ("L","R") and movement is forward only ("F") but not backward).

Not the most efficient, not succint/Pythonic, but hopefully a simple enough example to follow:

```py
def path_to_turtle(path):
        dir_to_turtle = {
            (0,0)  : '',
            (1,0)  : 'F',       # to the right: move forward
            (0,1)  : 'RF',      # bellow: turn right, then move forward
            (1,1)  : 'FRF',     # right diagonal down: move forward, turn right, then move forward again
            (-1,0) : 'RRF',     # left: turn right twice (180 degrees), then move forward
            (0,-1) : 'LF',      # up: turn left once (90 degrees), then move forward
            (-1,-1): 'LLFRF',   # left diagonal up: go back one (turn 180 then forward), turn right one (90 degrees) to point up, then go forward
            (1,-1) : 'FLF',     # right diagonal up: forward, turn left (90 degrees), (1,) then go forward (,-1)
            (-1,1) : 'RRFRF'    # left down diagonal: turn right twice (180 degrees), move forward (-1,), then turn right again (90 degrees) and forward agan (,1)
        }
        turtle = ""
        for i in range(len(path) - 1):
            curr_point = path[i]
            next_point = path[i+1]
            dx = next_point[0] - curr_point[0]
            dy = next_point[1] - curr_point[0]
            print(i,path[i],'->',path[i+1],'=',(dx, dy),dir_to_turtle[(dx,dy)])
            turtle += dir_to_turtle[(dx,dy)]
        # append \n if arduino buffers each char until new line
        turtle += '\n'
        return turtle
```

The above:

1. has a lookup of possible relative directions (up,down,left,right + 4 diagonals) converted to `F,L,R` commands
2. iterates through the path from the first until one before last point, two points at a time (current and next)
3. the difference between next and current (on each axis) is the movement direction: this is converted to commands using the lookup

This makes the assumption your robot is turtle like: top down view, left/right turns are 90 degrees.

The `print()` call inside the function is purely for debugging / visualisation reasons:

```
path = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6)]
step 0 (0, 0) -> (1, 1) = (1, 1) FRF
step 1 (1, 1) -> (2, 2) = (1, 1) FRF
step 2 (2, 2) -> (3, 3) = (1, 1) FRF
step 3 (3, 3) -> (4, 3) = (1, 0) F
step 4 (4, 3) -> (5, 4) = (1, 1) FRF
step 5 (5, 4) -> (6, 5) = (1, 1) FRF
step 6 (6, 5) -> (7, 6) = (1, 1) FRF
serial_commands FRFFRFFRFFFRFFRFFRF
```

The other assumption is the arduino firmware buffers each char until the new line character ('\n').

Using your `path` variable as the A* result, you should be able to something like this:

```py
import serial
serial_commands = path_to_turtle(path)
print(serial_commands)
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600)
try:
    arduino.write(str.encode(serial_commands))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)
```

For fun, I recommend playing with the turtle module.
It would allow you to build a basic emulator to tests paths before sending to the action robot.

Comment: Import serial code part serial_commands = path_to_turtle(path), VS write that path is not defined. How I can solve this problem.

Comment: It took me a few times of reading your comment to understand what you meant. If I understand correctly your asking how to put the parts (`astar`,`path_to_turle`,`serial`) together ? My assumption is that you know how to call functions and import modules in Python already, based on the code you posted. I suggest: 1. add the `path_to_turtle` function to your `astar` script (e.g. after `astar`, before `main`), 2. double check you can run the script, 3. call `print(path_to_turtle(path))` after `print(path)` in `main()`. At this stage you should see the serial commands. The next step is serial ...

Comment: ... add `import serial` at the top of the merged `astar/part_to_turtle` script, then, in `main`, you can store the serial commands to a string after calling astar (`serial_commands = path_to_turtle(path)`), initialise the serial connection and write those commands: `arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600)` and `arduino.write(str.encode(serial_commands))`. This assumes that's the right COM port, it's connected via USB and no other applications use it (e.g. Arduino Serial Monitor, etc.). You have all the "ingredients" above: you can do it, you can put these together, step by step.

Comment: I add **(module) serial** to top of the programm, but VS write that **''serial'' is not accessed**, how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If the error you're getting is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'` you need to install the serial module first. (e.g. running `pip install pyserial` in console/terminal, assuming pip is installed, otherwise you need to install pip first). How did you manage to run the first python script from your question (which uses serial) ?

Comment: To run the first script I install pyserial and it work fine.

Comment: I write 'print(path)
    print(path_to_turtle(path)) 
    serial_commands = path_to_turtle(path)
    print(serial_commands)
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600)
    arduino.write(str.encode(serial_commands))' in def main but it output me 2 times the second code what you write in answer and it dont turn on the motors.

Comment: sounds like you're on the right track: you're no longer getting `ModuleNotFoundError` on serial, you're getting the commands to send to arduino, etc. You're getting the message output twice because you're princing twice (once with  ` print(path_to_turtle(path))`, then later again with  `print(serial_commands)`). You can delete `print(path_to_turtle(path))` and you should see the output command once.

Now when it comes to debugging the Arduino there's many things that could go round and you need to troubleshoot. e.g. 1. is the Arduino connected via USB (and not opened in Serial Monitor)...

Comment: ...is the correct firmware(program) uploaded to the Arduino ? (e.g. if you close the python program and use Serial Monitor to send the command, do the motors turn ?

Comment: Does your Arduino program read one byte at a time and turn the motors immediately (if the right string is matched) or does it wait for two bytes (characters): e.g. a command (F,L or R) then a new line character (`\n`) (which SerialMonitor might send for you each time you hit enter) ? If the motors turn with Serial Monitor you should be able to send the same data from Python

Comment: If I use Arduino IDE motors turn on correctly and work properly.

Comment: _char x;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Informacija");
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT); //LF
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);  //LB
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);  //RF
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);  //RB
}
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    x = Serial.read();
    if (x=='F') {
      Serial.println("Robots brauc uz prieksu");
      digitalWrite(10,0);
      digitalWrite(9,1);
      digitalWrite(8,1);
      digitalWrite(7,0);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(10,0);
      digitalWrite(9,0);
      digitalWrite(8,0);
      digitalWrite(7,0); _ Here is part of arduino ide code

Comment: I believe my answer above addresses how to conver the output of the astar algorithm in a format that can work with the serial code you posted (assuming that section works correctly).  If my answer has been useful consider [voting up and it is the solution to your problem consider marking it with the green mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). The comments hint at a different question which I recommend you post separately (e.g. How to control an Arduino Robot from Python via Serial ) where you should ...

Comment: ...post your full Arduino code, your basic Python script to talk to the Arduino and clarify if that works or not (and in what you think fails). Without the actual hardware/time to test, I can only make (potentially inacurate assumptions) which may waste our time. [Reading PySerial's reference](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.__init__) I see `timeout=None` by default and reference further explains: "timeout = None: wait forever / until requested number of bytes are received". Maybe pyserial blocks until you read the `Serial.println` data from Arduino ?

Comment: try `arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout = 0)` (and if you want to double check communication is correct you can look at calling [`read_until()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until) to double check the commands are received on Arduino and send the expected messages back to Python. Depending how you set `timeout` (blocking/non-blocking), you may need a loop to keep the connection open and reat the full data back. If my hunch is correct, these are all details for a new specific question you should post, avoiding long comments.